# How to Append Integer to Integer Array in an Existing Row in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have created a Table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE parentChild
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  parentID integer,
  childIds integer[],
  CONSTRAINT PARENTCHILD_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I have also Inserted several elements in this table

Initial Table View

```
id | ParentID | ChildIDs
------------------------
1  | 0        | 
2  | 0        |
```

When I insert Child of "1" where child ID will be 3 and its parent ID will be 1, I wish to append 3 to the Child IDs integer array at id=1 as shown below.

```
id | ParentID | ChildIDs
------------------------
1  | 0        | 3,4
2  | 0        |
3  | 1        |
```

Could you please let me know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find array operators:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html

You can try this query:

```
Update parentChild
Set childid = childid || 3
Where id = 1
```